# CSS: Can't get text vertically aligned in box

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm displaying a series of boxes as `<li>s` like this:

[image]

I want the text vertically centered in the boxes, but as you can see they are way too low. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="pagelinks">
  <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>2</li></a>
    ...
    <a href="#"><li>6</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.pagelinks { float:right; margin:0; }
.pagelinks li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:15px;
    border:2px solid #394E7E;
    margin:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
.pagelinks a, .pagelinks a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
```

I already had a look at `vertically-align`, but I think it will align the `<li>` in the `<ul>`, not the text in the `<li>`.

How do I fix this?

*PS: in the accepted answer to a similar question it was suggested to use `<sub>/<sup>`, but I'm sure that **not** the way to do it.*

Comment: what is the font-size you are using?

Comment: You can control this by using .pagelinks li{ line-height:17px;}, and manage according to font-size and box height.

Comment: @MSRS - I tried scaling down the font-size, but that didn't really solve the problem. The line-height from the answers seems to do the trick. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @stevenvh - I asked you to give the same answer like others. To obtain the expected result you need set the line-height and height with equal size which should be more than the font-size you are using :)

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height.

```
li{
   line-height:15px; // the hight of the li
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rJn34/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-height: 15px;` to your li class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/2Q2ky/)**

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted is incorrectly formatted HTML. The `<a>` tag should be inside the `<li>`.

Also, remove the height from the `<li>` elements and just use `line-height` on the `<a>` tags.

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q2ky/2/)

Comment: What if I want to use the whole box as a link? If I write the a tag inside the li I have to click the text itself.

Comment: if the `<a>` tag has `display:block` it will fill up the whole box